# Sent date in server

Tags: date, extjs, calendar, format

Hello i am have datefield:

```
                   {
                        xtype: 'datefield',
                        height: 25,
                        flex: 1,
                        margin: '0 0 0 0',
                        textAlign: 'left',
                        padding: 0,
                        format: 'd.m.Y H:i'
                    }
```

And this field in model: `{ name: 'calendar', type: 'date' },` 
But when i am sent in server in request 'calendar' have this format `calendar: "3388463160"`, and then when i am get from server 'calendar'  i 
received this `calendar:"0001-01-01T00:00:00"`  How i can right format for server from extJs ?

Comment: [`dateFormat`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.field.Date-cfg-dateFormat) on the model.

Comment: i am use this: '{ name: 'calendar', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'd.m.Y H:i' }' and in request to server: calendar:"17.05.2016 11:20"  but when i get from server i am have this: calendar:"0001-01-01T00:00:00" and 'dateField' is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am add in field this: `{ name: 'calendar', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'c' }'` and all work right

Answer (score 0):

use submitFormat property for datefield

```
{
    xtype: 'datefield',
    height: 25,
    flex: 1,
    margin: '0 0 0 0',
    textAlign: 'left',
    padding: 0,
    submitFormat:'d.m.Y H:i',
    format: 'd.m.Y H:i'
}
```

Comment: thanks, model: '{ name: 'calendar', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'd.m.Y H:i' }', in dateField add: submitFormat:'d.m.Y H:i', when request to server: calendar:"17.05.2016 00:00" but get from server calendar:"0001-01-01T00:00:00" from server